# File write/read function like in PHP

Tags: java, file-io

So I'm learning new things day by day in Java, and I hope one day I should have same knowledge in Java as in PHP.

I'm trying to make a class that is similar to `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose` in PHP like:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '1');
fwrite($fp, '23');
fclose($fp);

// the content of 'data.txt' is now 123 and not 23!
?>
```

I also need the method of writing

**o** - for delete and write/overwrite

**a** - for append at end

and a read function that returns the the content line by line, so I can put it into an array , like **file_get_contents(file);**

This is what I have so far ...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/** 
Read and write a file using an explicit encoding.
Removing the encoding from this code will simply cause the 
system's default encoding to be used instead.  
**/
public final class readwrite_txt 
{

    /** Requires two arguments - the file name, and the encoding to use.  **/
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        String fileName = "text.txt";
        String encoding = "UTF-8";

        readwrite_txt test = new readwrite_txt(fileName,encoding);
        test.write("argument.txt","some text","UTF-8","o");
    }

    /** Constructor. **/
    readwrite_txt(String fileName, String encoding)
    {
        String fEncoding = "text.txt";
        String fFileName = "UTF-8";
    }

    /** Write fixed content to the given file. **/
    public void write(String fileName,String input,String encoding,String writeMethod) throws IOException  
    {
        // Method overwrite
        if(writeMethod == "o")
        {
            log("Writing to file named " + fileName + ". Encoding: " + encoding);
            Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), encoding);
            try 
            {
                out.write(input);
            }
            finally 
            {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /** Read the contents of the given file. **/
    public void read(String fileName,String output,String encoding,String outputMethod) throws IOException 
    {
        log("Reading from file.");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName), encoding);
        try 
        {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
            text.append(scanner.nextLine() + NL);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            scanner.close();
        }
        log("Text read in: " + text);
    }

    // Why write System.out... when you can make a function like log("message"); simple!
    private void log(String aMessage)
    {
    System.out.println(aMessage);
    }
}
```

also, I don't understand why I must have

```
readwrite_txt test = new readwrite_txt(fileName,encoding);
```

instead of

```
readwrite_txt test = new readwrite_txt();
```

I just want to have an simple function similar to that in PHP.

**EDITED**

So my function must be

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w'); ==> readwrite_txt test = new readwrite_txt(filename,encoding,writeMethod);

fwrite($fp, '23');            ==> test.write("the text");

fclose($fp);                  ==> ???
```

Answer (score 2):

to read a file in java you can

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String strLine;

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) //Start of reading file
{
    //what you want to do with every line is here 
}
```

but for `readwrite_txt test = new readwrite_txt();` problem .. 
you must have another constructor inside the class that doesn't take any parameters

Comment: works, but i have to make it like a function, which it might return an array, the idea is that everything must be ordered and elegant ...

Comment: To return an array you can use an ArrayList of String, you can read more about that class here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html. You should add all the lines from your buffer to this ArrayList and return the ArrayList. If you are using Java, forget about simple functions, everything should be part of a class. This has a lot of upsides and a lot of drawbacks too.

Comment: So your problem is in returning the array ?!
Arraylists will solve your problem for sure

this is a dummy code for it 

`ArrayList<String> array=new ArrayList<String>(); 
array.add("1"); 
array.add("2"); 
array.clear();`

Comment: no, my main problem is making everything a class, in this example i intend to make a class to be similar with the function in PHP, i should learn some skills by this examples, i know what i'm saying

Comment: i have EDITED my post, take a look please and see what i mean about "a function like in PHP", thank you :)

Comment: Well, I wish you good luck and whenever you are stuck, you can use google or stackoverflow to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following file handling tutorials (Google is littered with them):

- http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42
- http://www.coderanch.com/t/403914/java/java/do-read-entire-file-all

Pay attention to the following classes:

- FileInputStream
- FileOutpuStream
- Scanner

There's all sorts of examples out there for you to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BufferedReader, [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/java/slides/sd2000east/javaio/56.html) is an example and BufferedWriter, [here](http://www.javadb.com/write-to-file-using-bufferedwriter) is an example of write and [here](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/2452-open-a-bufferedwriter-file-in-append-mode.html) is an example for appending. For reading line-by-line you can use the readLine method of BufferedReader. You don't need those parameters in your constructor, because you don't use them, but you don't even need a class to implement these features because there are already standard classes for this purpose.

I hope this helps.

Comment: interesting, but is there a way to make it look like in PHP ? if that's not a recomanded method do make a class to look like in PHP, fine, i'm reading/writing JAVA style ...

Comment: Java is a class based object oriented technology. You should never explicitly want your Java code to look like a PHP code because the two technologies have different paradigms behind them. There is no point to reinvent the wheel, you should use the standard classes whenever possible, the exceptions being cases when they are unable to do something. But even then it's a better option to extend/implement the given standard class than writing a new class from 0. It's better to get used to Java style if you want to work in Java, it's easier to understand other codes if nothing else.

Comment: Java is not that evil as it may look like at first glance, you can do pretty nice stuff with Java, but wanting to write code in Java in PHP style is like wanting to speak English with a German accent. It might work out, but you will always be in disadvantage. It's much better to work on your accent when you learn a new language. You might write excellent German poems, but it's better to speak English without an accent if possible, if you know what I mean.

Comment: hmm, thanks, i'll take your advice, now i'm making some applets, i really wish to learn java, at least it's not evil as objectice c ...